# Suitable usage of "cultivated"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Here is the scenario:
An actor is not so good looking but he cultivated a personality that no one can disapprove of.

Is the sentence right? Can you suggest better synonym of "cultivated"?

Comment: You can cultivate (figuratively speaking) a hobby, friendships, a network and "a taste for + noun" and it's often used in rural contexts; such as cultivate the land, fields, crops etc. So how would an actor "cultivate" his own personality? You don't *look after* a personality, or *help it thrive and grow*. We can guess its meaning but it's a bit stretched.

Answer (score 3):

*[Cultivate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cultivate#Verb)*, with its sense  “To nurture; to foster; to tend” can indeed be used as in the question's example sentence, but the usage isn't perfectly natural.  One may be said to cultivate friends, if one pays attention to starting and keeping friendships; one may be said to cultivate good habits; but cultivating one's personality seems to me rather more problematic.

If you mean he started out with  a personality no one can disapprove of, you might say he *possesses* or *has* such a personality.  If he purposefully developed such a personality, you might say *developed* or *portrays*.  I don't recommend *cultivated* in this context, but beyond personal preference (as a native speaker) don't have a good excuse for not recommending it.

Comment: Maybe it feels odd because _cultivate_ means to grow in a managed way, which rarely applies to oneself. Most celebrities seem to cultivate an _image_ of their personality.

Comment: To me, *cultivated* means something different than *developed* or *possesses*: the fact that he worked to maintain and strenghten it (perfectly in line with your "to nurture; to foster; to tend"). He might or might not have started out with such a personality, but he did not let it develop on its own, but rather paid attention to engineer change in himself that would make him into a specific kind of person, or closer to such an ideal than he was before. Just like you might water a sapling every day, he might have consciously and calculatedly been doing a good deed every day.

Comment: @Amadan, I agree the meanings of those words differ.  I don't agree  *cultivated* is an appropriate choice here.

Answer (score 0):

How about the word unblemished

describes a reputation, character, etc. that has no faults and is not spoiled in any way

i.e    For six years his championship record was unblemished.

An actor is not so good looking but he cultivated an **unblemished** personality

Comment: Not an answer to this question, I'm afraid. OP is asking about "cultivated", not "that no one can disapprove of".

Comment: Haha my bad didn't read it properly.